# Why redirect on my website only works for once?

Tags: javascript, html

On my website, I made a redirect page to redirect people according to their languages and browsers. But it only works once, when I visit my website again, it won't redirect.

HTML:

```
<html lang="zh-CN">
<head>
    <script>
        function redirect(){
            // redirect according to browsers
            var temp = window.navigator.userAgent.toUpperCase();
            var charHead = temp.indexOf('MSIE');
            var charLast = temp.indexOf(";", charHead);
            var ieVersion = temp.substring(charHead, charLast);
            ieVersion = ieVersion.split(' ')[1];
            if (ieVersion <= 8) {
                window.location.href="https://compat.windowsme.xyz:914";
            } 

            if (localStorage.getItem("visit") == null)
            {
                // redirect according to user language
                console.log("redirecting...")
                var language = navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage; //for IE
                if (language == 'zh-CN'){
                    document.location.href = 'zh-index.html';
                }
                else if (language == 'zh-HK' || language == 'zh-TW'){
                    document.location.href = 'hant-index.html';
                }
                else {
                    document.location.href = 'en-index.html';
                }
            }

            localStorage.setItem("visit", new Date());
            redirect()
        }
    </script>
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>redirect</title>
</head>
<body onload="redirect()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because for the second time `localStorage.getItem("visit")` is not null?

Comment: I don't understand. You _specifically_ have code that makes sure it redirects only once by storing the last visit in local storage and checking for it, and you are complaining about the code... working? Just remove that logic...

Comment: (but then also remove the recursive call - I'm not sure why it exists anyway)

Answer (score 0):

It's because on the second visit the item in LocalStorage is not null anymore. Why do you store this information? If you remove the if handler, it will work on every site visit.